# How to show label but not move other elements in div?

Tags: css, angularjs

I have this div:

```
div class="@b.ClassTag">
<h1>SEARCH</h1>
<p>ENTER_PIN:</p>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="pin">
<label style="color:red;" ng-show="NotFound">NOT_FOUND"</label>
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn btn-search" ng-click="ShowDetails(pin);">
</div>
```

It looks fine when label is hide but when user click on submit button and label displays buton goes on bottom, so how can i display label but that not disrupt or move button

Comment: so you want `label` and `button` in same alignment ? can you show in fiddle or distorted screenshot ?

Comment: Put a float: left/right on label & input. Would be helpful if you put together a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or you can set `position:absolute;` on label and then it wont have effect on other elements, but you will have to position label to the right place